# Show CSS/HTML depending on a word/url existing in the code

Tags: javascript, html, css, search

I've been searching for this and I've not find anything like I want to implement on my website.

The idea is, to show some html code or changing some css stuff IF a word or url is present or not in the code. 
For example, if I want to show a widget if the word `banana` it's not in the code... or if the url `http://bleble/tagged/banana` is not in the code...?
How do I do this?

I suppose that it would have to be with javascript and a conditional but I just know CSS+HTML.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

```
window.onload = function() {
// Funcion hecha por Welele antes de usarla pide permiso.
var enlaces = document.getElementsByTagName("a");var contador = 0;
for(var i=0; i<enlaces.length; i++) 
{
if(enlaces[i].href == "http://welele.es/tagged/azas" || enlaces[i].href == "http://welele.es/tagged/azas/") 
    { contador++;}
    if(contador>2){break;}        
}
if(contador>2){$('#goviral').addClass('oculto');}}
```

The idea is.. if contador (counter) is more than 2 the class oculto will be added to goviral id (oculto class is .oculto {display:none} ) And its working... ;) I suppose that is not the most efficient code possible but it's my first javascript ever.

Answer (score 0):

```
var txt = document.querySelector("textarea").value; // pretending the string is
                                                    // from a <textarea>
if(txt.search(/banana/i)==-1){
    //show widget
}

// -or-

var key = new RegExp("http://bleble/tagged/banana","i");
if(txt.search(key)==-1){
    //show widget
}
```

Comment: I've implemented another solution... made by myself... I think is not that bad if we bear in mind that I didn't know anything about javascript till this day... I'll add it in the original message

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript for a functional operation isn't best practice.

Is your site going to soley be on HTML CSS?

Are you using a CMS, if so you could do some server-side scripting.

Comment: Is a tumblr so.. I can implement any code I need.. I just don't know wich to use and how to implement what I want.